# QThreadPool and QRunnable performance for many tasks/threads

Tags: multithreading, performance, qt, threadpool

I have a piece of code that needs to perform 18 million tasks.  I'm currently using Qt, and more specifically a QThreadPool with QRunnables to multithread the operation on my 8 core CPU.

I have a single QRunnable class that encapsulates and implements the task that must be repeated 18 million times.  I'm wondering what the overhead of spooling QRunnables across the QThreadPool is.  If there is appreciable overhead, this will accumulate over the 18 million QRunnables that must be pushed through the QThreadPool.

I'm wondering if it makes sense to instead break the 18 million tasks up into larger chunks, where say each QRunnable implements 10,000 tasks instead of one.  Would this reduce the overall computation time by removing overhead associated with QRunnable assignments and deallocations in the QThreadPool?

I guess the real question is: is the overhead of starting QRunnables in a QThreadPool high enough to add significant computation time if using 18million QRunnables?

Thanks all!

Comment: `QThreadPool` has some small overhead. Batching may be useful. Whether this overhead is relevant, depends on the time needed to perform one task.

Comment: The only way to find out is to test different vairants and measure the time. But as @m7913d already said, it largely depends on the size of the tasks. Depending on what you do, QtConcurrent might or might not be even more efficient